# Why is my $scope variable only updated in the HTML and not in the controller when using Bootstrap with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using UI Bootstrap from Angular to show a modal overlay where the user can select an item in a select box. The value the user selects should be available in the overlay's controller to send back to the opening controller. In the HTML for the modal, this works:

```
<select
     ng-model="selectedItem"
     ng-options="item for item in items">
</select>
Selected: <b>{{ selectedItem }}</b>
```

but in the controller, this is always undefined:

```
$scope.selectedItem;
```

Why can I not access this value in my controller?

The project I am working on has a few more moving parts (I am using the typeahead and buttons directives instead of a simple select) but I slimmed down the problem to this working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/lb0NAGLR8eEVrywA67EC?p=preview.  In this example, the selection in the modal should be shown on the parent page when the modal is closed.

Comment: Strange fact: If you exchange $scope.selectedItem for this.selectedItem in the ok() function it works. $scope seems to have been copied after initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to create a child scope for the HTML inside the modal besides the one created in the controller.  See the ids in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qaOIUlCGfa4TzAM3y98R?p=preview) when you open the modal.

So the gist is that you are setting 'selectedItem' on the child's scope, which isn't available on the scope you have access to in your modal instance controller.  There are two ways to solve this:

**Option 1**
Take an argument in your 'ok' function and pass it the result in your HTML [(*plunker*)](http://plnkr.co/edit/yNTOKcPQpSDonkrAJS8R?p=preview):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok(selectedItem)">OK</button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.ok = function (arg) {
  $modalInstance.close(arg);
};
```

**Option 2**
Create an object in the controller that will inherit to the child scope for setting properties on.  This is what the [sample code](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) does.

When `selectedItem` is set by angular it is set on the child scope your controller knows nothing about and it does not propagate to the parent scope.  If you set the value on an inherited object it will change the property on the inherited object and you can access it in your controller [(*plunker*)](http://plnkr.co/edit/HRAh1goBsGlFxbeXQaGq?p=preview):

```
<select
     ng-model="selected.Item"
     ng-options="item for item in items">
</select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.ok = function () {
  $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.Item);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create a modal dialog using AngularUI Bootstrap, a new child scope is created.

What this means is that the `$scope` inside your `ModalInstanceCtrl` is actually the parent scope of the scope of the HTML. (Don't ask me why they built it this way.)

To prove this point, change

`ng-model="selectedItem"` to `ng-model="$parent.selectedItem"`

and change

`Selected: <b>{{ selectedItem }}</b>` to `Selected: <b>{{ $parent.selectedItem }}</b>`.

Voila! It works.

A better solution is to just change the `ok()` method to accept the child scope's `selectedItem` as follows:

```
ng-click="ok(selectedItem)"

// Then, in the controller
$scope.ok = function (selectedItem) {
    $modalInstance.close(selectedItem);
};
```

For a more complete explanation about what's happening, read [this article](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html).

Comment: I read that comment in the Bootstrap docs, but I interpreted it as original scope = ModalDemoCtrl, child scope = ModalInstanceCtrl. It seems that there are three scopes at work here, that of ModalDemoCtrl, ModalInstanceCtrl and ModalInstanceCtrl's HTML? If this is the case, why can I access $scope.ok() in the ng-click?

Comment: Because scopes are prototypical. If a property can't be found in the current scope, it looks in the parent scope, and so on. The `ok()` method is not in the HTML scope, but in its parent's scope (the Ctrl scope). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selectedItem);
```

to

```
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
```

And in the html

```
    <div class="modal-body">
        <select
             ng-model="selected.item"
             ng-options="item for item in items">
        </select>
        Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
    </div>
```

Updated plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/TuwPqtNeQwBVeXU2ncIe?p=preview